# Using if condition blocks with Refcursor in Pl/SQl

Tags: oracle10g, if-statement, sys-refcursor

I have created a package of of type RefCursor.

I am using package in my stored procedure.

code looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PRODDB.types
AS
type cursorType is ref cursor;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRODDB.P_Get_AdminPLCReport         
(        
    Final_Output out TYPES.cursorType

)        
AS

BEGIN       
IF( Criteria='1') THEN        
  OPEN Final_Output FOR 
  SELECT  Personal_Information.F_Salutation
  FROM    Allotment_Information;

END IF;

END P_Get_AdminPLCReport;
```

I want to use two if conditions in this stored procedure.

I am new to Pl-Sql.

Can anybody help me by telling me the syntax for this.

Thanx

--

**Update**

Thanx Justin ([response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822995/using-if-condition-blocks-with-refcursor-in-pl-sql/5823274#5823274)),

But i want to use two condition like:

IF( criteria = '1') then

// some query; end if

IF( criteria = '2') then

// some query;

end if

I will pass value of param criteria.

Based on the value of criteria , i want to execute different queries.

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is no need to define a weakly typed `REF CURSOR` in a TYPES package in 10g.  That was necessary in some older releases, but Oracle has a `SYS_REFCURSOR` type now.

Second, your procedure doesn't compile because there is no declaration of the variable `Criteria`.  I'll ignore that and assume that you have declared and initialized the variable elsewhere.

Depending on what the second condition is, the simplest option would generally be something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRODDB.P_Get_AdminPLCReport 
(
  Final_Output OUT sys_refcursor
)
AS
BEGIN
  IF( criteria = '1' and someOtherCriteria = '2' )
  THEN
    OPEN final_output FOR
      SELECT personal_information.f_salutation
        FROM allotment_information;
  END IF;
END p_get_adminPLCReport;
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys_refcursor` is still a weakly typed ref cursor. Look at the definition of `sys_refcursor` in the data dictionary and you will see this:

`type sys_refcursor` is ref cursor;